# Concurrency control in database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am implementing an online judge.The submission of a user goes into the `submission` table of
the database.The table has an attribute `status` which is initially `Queued`. My program connects to the database and sees for submissions in `submission` table with `Queued` status, if yes picks one of them and  turns the status to `Assessing`. Then the submission is compiled and run against the test cases.Then according to the result the `status` attribute is changed to `Accepted`,`Wrong Answer` etc.
My question is that if I run my program on two different machines with the same database,the two programs can give a concurrency issue.For example if I make a submission , it will have status=`Queued`,now suppose the first program reads it first and before it changes the
status=`Assessing`,the second program also reads the submission.Now there is no error as re-evaluation of same submission is taking place.
But still does `Mysql` provides concurrency in such a case or I have to add it my self.If yes
what is the best method ?

Comment: look up row versioning...

Comment: You should consider using a job queuing platform like resque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved with read locks. There is good documentation with examples http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: can you tell how to put locks in the case I described above

Comment: You might get more answers if you edit your question with details of what you've tried already, and what problems you're having. People don't generally want to just solve a problem for you.

Comment: @Cylindric the problem i am having now is that if one of the program reads a submission I set a lock on it but it does not prevent another program for waiting for the lock to be released and re-evaluating the submission which i don't want.I have included everything above if somthing is not please tell me i will do so

Comment: You should be running statements in a transcation with autocommit set to false. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html. Depending on language you are using to code your program, there should be way to specify these properties while obtaining connection.